# MailChimp - Sending the welcome email instantly

Tags: mailchimp

Normally once a user signs up to my website the "welcome" email is delivered to the subscriber after one hour (default from the MailChimp).

How can I instantly send this welcome email to a user once they complete the signup form on my site.

Is there any way I can do this through the MailChimp API or some custom coding?

Comment: Hey i am wondering how can i send mail through mailChimp after registration can you show some code that  would be really helpful to me thanks

Comment: @Vivekh this is a default feature in Mailchimp.